# startswith() in Python acting unexpectedly

Tags: python, string, startswith

I have the following simple Python code that support to ask if a player wants to play the game again or not.

```
print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
if not input('> '.lower().startswith('y')):
    print('no')
else:
    print('yes')
```

However, it does not work correctly.  When I run it, it prints a "False" out of nowhere.  And regardless if I enter "yes" or "no", the outcome is always "yes".

```
Do you want to play again? (yes or no)
Falseyes
yes

Do you want to play again? (yes or no)
Falseno
yes
```

But the following code works.

```
print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
again = input('> '.lower())
print(again)
again = again.startswith('y')
print(again)
```

results:

```
Do you want to play again? (yes or no)
> yes
yes
True

Do you want to play again? (yes or no)
> no
no
False
```

Comment: You misplaced a close parentheses: `if not input('> '.lower().startswith('y')):` should be `if not input('> ').lower().startswith('y'):` so you convert to lowercase and test the *result* of the `input('> ')` call, rather than passing the result of performing those operations on `'> '` to `input`, then testing the unmodified result of `input` for emptiness (which, if you enter anything, the `not` will convert it to `False`, and only return `True` when you enter nothing). Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
if not input('> ').lower().startswith('y'):
    print('no')
else:
    print('yes')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong position. You want to call `.lower().startswith('y')` on the result of `input('> ')`.

Change this:

```py
if not input('> '.lower().startswith('y')):
```

to:

```py
if not input('> ').lower().startswith('y'):
```

Comment: For "typo" questions it is probably better to just give the answer in the comments. The question will be deleted eventually, and not answering makes it easier to delete.